# django templates, find string replace with other string

Tags: django, templates

Hay, I'm writing some templates but I want to convert " " into "_" within a string.

I want to convert the output of

```
{{ user.name }}
```

from something like "My Name" to "My_Name". How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no built-in tag or filter to do this replacement. Write a filter that splits by a given character, and then combine that with the `join` filter, or write a filter that does the replacement directly.

Comment: Seems that i cannot use custom filters with a inclusion, any ideas?

Comment: For future visitors, see @daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6735266/1526703) below, just use `{{ user.name.split|join:"_" }}` which works only for whitespaces.

Answer (score 93):

A shorter version of Matthijs' answer:

```
{{ user.name.split|join:"_" }}
```

Of course it only works when splitting on whitespace.

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I needed!

Comment: WOW ! how did I miss that ?

Comment: my user.name value is 'a.b' How to replace '.' with '_' in django template?

Answer (score 10):

I like to perform this type of conversions in my view / controller code i.e.:

```
user.underscored_name = user.name.replace(' ','_')
context['user'] = user
```

dont be afraid to just add a new (temporary) property and use this in your template:

```
{{ user.underscored_name }}
```

If you use this at more places add the method underscored_name to the User model:

```
class User()
  def underscored_name(self):
    return self.name.replace(' ','_')
```

Comment: This works as long as the attribute is not called by a django html page. Recommend setting a `self.underscored_name` field in the class. +1 anyway because it helped me solve a problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont like to write your own custom tag you could do it like this ...

```
{% for word in user.name.split %}{{word}}{% if not forloop.last %}_{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

However its quite verbose ...