# dealing with spaces in URLs in Django's templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-haystack

I'm working on a Django template that displays search results from a Haystack search (I'm basing my template off the code at http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#setting-up-the-views). The problem is that queries can contain spaces (e.g., I search for "lyme disease"), and these spaces aren't handles properly in URLs.

If I search for "lyme disease", this is the URL I get:

```
http://www.site.com/search/?q=lyme+disease&type=All+Types
```

That's fine. There's nothing wrong with that. However, I'm using pagination, and I've got Next and Previous links that I build. What I want is to have Next point to:

```
http://www.site.com/search/?q=lyme+disease&type=All+Types&page=2
```

However, that's not what's happens. The link I get is this:

```
http://www.site.com/search/?q=lyme disease&type=All Types&page=2
```

The template code I'm using to generate the Next link is this:

```
{% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;type={{ request.GET.type }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
```

My question is this: how can I escape `query` and `request.GET.type` so that spaces are converted back into +? I've tried the [`escape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escape) and [`force_escape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#force-escape) template tags, but they don't escape spaces. I know [there's a hacky way to call `str.replace` in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185133/django-templates-find-string-replace-with-other-string), but is there a better, official way to solve this problem?

[edit]
I forgot to mention that `urlencode` doesn't work. I'm not sure why, but `{{ query|urlencode }}` still contains spaces.

Comment: I think you should update the question to mention that `urlencode` filter doesn't work.

Comment: that is very wierd :). Just a shot in the dark, Does `request.GET.type|safe|urlencode` make any difference?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either.

Comment: I just tried `{{ query.split|join:'+' }}`, and that does work. It's just really hacky. Django surely already has a way to handle spaces in URLs, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def remove_spaces(value):
    return value.replace(' ', '+')
```

Maybe an additional `urlencode` makes also sense if you can't guarantee that the string will only contain url safe letters! The most elegant solution would be to make a custom template tag/filter which generates the whole query string out of the `request.GET` QueryDict, so that you don't have to deal with string concatenation in the template itself (see eg. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-urltags/).

As an alternative you could also generate the "next" link in your view and pass it to your template...

Comment: I like the custom filter idea! I think I'll do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For now, I've solved the problem by doing `{{ query.split|join:'+' }}`. It feels hacky; I feel like Django ought to have a built-in mechanism for cleaning the various parts of a URL. `urlencode` should be that mechanism, but it's not working.

I'm certainly open to better solutions!